# access to switch statement parameter value from a global variable

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I am learning javascript by making a project. I'm having trouble understanding global variables. In this example when I assign `variable = result;` ub the `randomvariable()` function ,  on the switch parameter of  `test()` function it doesn't work

```
function randomvariable () {
    var myarray = new Array;

    myarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    randomvariable  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0);
    result = (myarray[randomvariable]);  
   }

function test() {       
    switch (result) {
        case 0:
        alert("haahhaha");
        break; 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you declare a variable with `var` within a function, that variable is accessible from only that function. If you don't declare the variable with `var`, it becomes (by default) global and is accessible from anywhere.  This is a bad practice and should be avoided. Declaring a variable should always be done explicitly as to avoid confusion.

Now, the catch is that you must execute the function containing the variable for the variable's scope to go into effect. In your case, you are never actually executing the `randomvariable` function, so `result = ...` never gets executed and the global variable doesn't get created. In addition, you are never invoking the `test` function either.

Also, you are reassigning the `randomevariable` value from the function to the result of the random calculation. That is not what you should do. Instead, you can have the function `return` that result or just have the function set the variable.

```js
// Declare result in the Global scope
var result = null;

function randomvariable () {
    var myarray = new Array;

    myarray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    
    // This is the correct code for getting one of the array values randomly,
    // but we'll comment it out here so that we can force the value of 0 for
    // testing purposes
    //result = (myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)]);  
    result = 0;
}

function test() {
  // Generate the random number by invoking the function that does that work
  randomvariable();
  
  // Now, the global has a value assigned to it
  console.log(result);
  
  switch (result) {
    case 0:
        alert("haahhaha");
        break; 
  }   
}

// Now, invoke test to get the whole thing working
test();
```

Having said all of this, Global variables should be avoided as they create the possibility of colliding with other variables that exist at the same scope.  Always try to give your variables the smallest scope you can that allows your code to run. Globals are notorious sources for bugs.